# Catching Errors in MySQLdb Library

Tags: python, mysql

To prevent connections from being left open on the server - here's what I'm currently doing to close mysqldb's cursor and connection, then I re-raise the error:

```
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect(user="username", passwd="secret", db="database", charset='utf8')
cur = conn.cursor()

try:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO testTable (userid) VALUES(%s);" % id)
    conn.commit()
except:
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    raise
finally:
    print "Insert Successful"
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Note: I know the WITH keyword might be better, but I haven't found any documentation saying mysqldb supports the WITH keyword to close the connection automatically.

Comment: you must close connections in finaly, also the print in finaly should go after conn.commit()

Comment: [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#finally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/)

Cited:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb as mdb

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'testuser', 'test623', 'testdb');

with con:

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Writers")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Writers(Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, \
             Name VARCHAR(25))")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES('Jack London')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES('Honore de Balzac')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES('Lion Feuchtwanger')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES('Emile Zola')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES('Truman Capote')")
    ...
```